# Converting relative (‘m’) command to absolute (‘M’) commands in SVG files

Tags: svg

I like to understand how I can change SVG path which contains relative (‘m’) command to absolute (‘M’) commands. I have created two identical paths where Green path should cover Black, but that is not is case. How SVG compiler render relative path. Your help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Please include the SVG in the question. If in the future you update or delete that external file, then this question will be useless to others.

Comment: The exact definition on how path commands behave can be found in [the SVG specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/single-page.html#chapter-paths).

Comment: <path stroke-width="5" stroke="black" d="M21.52,184.48 H91.11 v-.07 H21.54 l0,.07Z
M469,147.4 q1.62,0,3.21,.12 l-406.4,0 c.67,-.05,1.35,-.09,2,-.12 l401.16,0Z
m8.55,.76,10.22,10 H60.82 l23.56,-.1 h6 l-5.47,.06Z
m6,5.2,10.7,10.15,-419.89,0,.4,-.09,418.79,0Z" transform="translate(0 -100)"/>

Comment: <path stroke-width="5" stroke="green" d="M21.52,184.48 L91.11,184.48 L91.11,184.41 L21.54,184.41 L21.54,184.48Z
 M469,147.4 Q470.62,147.4,472.21,147.52 L65.81,147.52 C66.48,147.47,67.16,147.43,67.81,147.4 L468.97,147.4Z
 M477.52,148.16 L487.74,158.16 L60.82,158.16 L84.38,158.06 L90.38,158.06 L84.91,158.12Z
 M90.91,163.32 L101.61,173.47 L-318.28,173.47 L-317.88,173.38 L100.91,173.38Z" transform="translate(0 -100)" />

Comment: Put them in the question. Please make a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

In SVG files a letter represents a command followed by some arguments. The lower command letter represents relative coordinates where upper case represents absolute coordinates. The Z commands the closing loop. The closing loop means the pen has gone back to the same position where it started. In my case I was not going back to the same position which gave me the bad output. Please note in case of small 'm' we have to add coordinates the previous absolute coordinates.
Now my application works fine.